# How to create submenu/drop down menu in wordpress 3.8.1 Bizway theme

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, submenu

Is the anyone who can help me with creating submenus for my wordpress site?

I want the Menu structure to be like this and to be a dropdown list menu:

- Home
- About Us
- Products

  - L'Oreal Products
  - Eco Kids Products
  - Bonacure Products
- Services
- Gallery
- Awards
- Contact Us

Am still new to wordpress,please take it easy on me..;-)

Here is a link to the site:
http://hairimpressions.azurewebsites.net/

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Go to your wp backend `Dashboard` -> `Appearance` -> `Menu` & set menu accordingly.

Comment: this link will be help full for you http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: Thank I will try recommended solution now and mark it as closed once all is working

Comment: I think my wordpress site has a real problem I cant save/update/delete any thing its just load but nothing happens, I was trying to save my menu its just load and doesn't save it, any suggestion I can use?

Answer (score 0):

First create page which you want to put as a sub menu then go to appearance>menu in that select page and add in to menu but just put under the main menu/or the page you want to create a submenu in...